# Kernel upgrade and Oracle prerequisites error

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, puppet, oracle, amazon-ami

I am upgrading kernel (Red Hat) from 6.7 to 6.9 with Amazon AMI and when I am installing Oracle through puppet I am getting this pre-requisite error.

```
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install gcc-c++' returned 1: Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.i686 (Repo)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.107.el6_4.2
           Installed: glibc-common-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.x86_64 (installed)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.209.el6_9.2
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.x86_64 (Repo)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.107.el6_4.2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
Error: /Stage[main]/Oracledb::Prereq/Package[gcc-c++]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install gcc-c++' returned 1: Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.i686 (Repo)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.107.el6_4.2
           Installed: glibc-common-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.x86_64 (installed)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.209.el6_9.2
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.x86_64 (Repo_New)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.107.el6_4.2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install elfutils-libelf-devel.x86_64' returned 1: Error: Package: elfutils-libelf-devel-0.152-1.el6.x86_64 (Repo
           Requires: elfutils-libelf(x86-64) = 0.152-1.el6
           Installed: elfutils-libelf-0.164-2.el6.x86_64 (installed)
               elfutils-libelf(x86-64) = 0.164-2.el6
           Available: elfutils-libelf-0.152-1.el6.x86_64 (Repo)
               elfutils-libelf(x86-64) = 0.152-1.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
Error: /Stage[main]/Oracledb::Prereq/Package[elfutils-libelf-devel.x86_64]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install elfutils-libelf-devel.x86_64' returned 1: Error: Package: elfutils-libelf-devel-0.152-1.el6.x86_64 (Repo)
           Requires: elfutils-libelf(x86-64) = 0.152-1.el6
           Installed: elfutils-libelf-0.164-2.el6.x86_64 (installed)
               elfutils-libelf(x86-64) = 0.164-2.el6
           Available: elfutils-libelf-0.152-1.el6.x86_64 (Repo)
               elfutils-libelf(x86-64) = 0.152-1.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0):

You have installed two (or maybe more?) custom yum repos on this system, named "Repo" and "Repo_New". These repos appear to be version locked to EL 6.4. You should remove these custom repos and replace them with the originals, or fix them.